# Não esta funcionando <th> text-align

Tags: html, css

Meu código que apresenta o problema e este:

html:

```
  <body>
    <table class="default_grid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="opcao1">Opção 1</th>
          <th class="opcao2">Opção 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
```

css:

```
{
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.default_grid {
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  color: white;
}

.default_grid .opcao1 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.default_grid .opcao2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

O problema aparece no internet explorer, o testo fica centralizao, não esta alinhado na esquerda, como resolver isso ?

```css
{
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
.default_grid {
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  color: white;
}
.default_grid .opcao1 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.default_grid .opcao2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="default_grid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="opcao1">Opção 1</th>
        <th class="opcao2">Opção 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Acho que no IE tens mesmo de colocar `.default_grid th { text-align: left;}`. Já testaste isso?

Comment: Acabei de testar, resolveu! Poste como resposta para poder marcar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers diferentes aplicam as [recomendações da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TH) de maneira diferente. O Internet Explorer pelos vistos não permite herança da propriedade `text-align` em `<th>`, que é centrada automáticamente. Assim tens de aplicar a regra na propria `th`:

```
.default_grid th { text-align: left;}
```